# continue scanning another site when issue comes up

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to scan a list of websites to check wether the following website is developed on wordpress or not. However, I am experiencing an issue in case of site `appears to be online but returned a 404 error.` I have to use `exit()` to exit the program otherwise i get `RemoteConnection` closed issue.

here is the code to scan websites

```
import requests

user_agent=None
# user agent so it doesn't show as python and get blocked, set global for request that need to allow for redirects
def get(websiteToScan):
    global user_agent
    user_agent = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36',
    }
    return requests.get(websiteToScan, allow_redirects=False, headers=user_agent)

def findWpStatus(websiteToScan):
    if websiteToScan.startswith('http://'):
        proto = 'http://'
        websiteToScan = websiteToScan[7:]
    elif websiteToScan.startswith('https://'):
        proto = 'https://'
        websiteToScan = websiteToScan[8:]
    else:
        proto = 'http://'
    # Check the input for an ending / and remove it if found
    if websiteToScan.endswith('/'):
        websiteToScan = websiteToScan.strip('/')
    # Combine the protocol and site
    websiteToScan = proto + websiteToScan
    # Check to see if the site is online
    print ("Checking to see if the site is online...")
    try:
        onlineCheck = get(websiteToScan)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as ex:
        print (f"{websiteToScan} appears to be offline.")
    else:
        if onlineCheck.status_code == 200 or onlineCheck.status_code == 301 or onlineCheck.status_code == 302:
            print (f"{websiteToScan} appears to be online.")
            print ("Beginning scan...")
            print ("Checking to see if the site is redirecting...")
            redirectCheck = requests.get(websiteToScan, headers=user_agent)
            if len(redirectCheck.history) > 0:
                if '301' in str(redirectCheck.history[0]) or '302' in str(redirectCheck.history[0]):
                    print ("[!] The site entered appears to be redirecting, please verify the destination site to ensure accurate results!")
                    print (f"It appears the site is redirecting to {redirectCheck.url}")
            elif 'meta http-equiv="REFRESH"' in redirectCheck.text:
                print ("The site entered appears to be redirecting, please verify the destination site to ensure accurate results!")
            else:
                print ("Site does not appear to be redirecting...")
        else:
            print (f"{websiteToScan} appears to be online but returned a {str(onlineCheck.status_code)} error.")
            exit()
        print ("Attempting to get the HTTP headers...")

        ####################################################
        # WordPress Scans
        ####################################################
        # Use requests.get allowing redirects otherwise will always fail
        wpLoginCheck=requests.get(websiteToScan + '/wp-login.php', headers=user_agent)
        if wpLoginCheck.status_code == 200:
            return 'Yes'
        return 'No'

websites = ["http://www.autofi.com","https://www.autograph.me", "http://autoidinc.com",
          "http://www.automatedinsights.com", "http://automatic.com","https://automationhero.ai", "https://www.automile.com", "https://www.automizy.com", "https://www.automotivemastermind.com",
          "https://www.automox.com", "http://www.autonetmobile.com", "http://autonomic.ai",
          "http://www.autonomoushealthcare.com", "http://www.automarinesys.com",
          "http://www.autopilothq.com", "http://autoref.com", "http://www.autovirt.com",
          "https://www.autzu.com", "http://www.ava.me", "http://www.eatwithava.com",
]

for website in websites:
  findWpStatus(website)
```

I get RemoteConnectionClosed issue so i had to do exit() to exit the overall program.

How can i handle such issue? I have created a repl to see the demo as well

https://repl.it/repls/ScalyGoldenPostgres

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the site http://autoref.com. They appear to be closing the socket without sending any response at all. To get around this add a try except block around your requests.

```py
try:
    wpLoginCheck=requests.get(websiteToScan + '/wp-login.php', headers=user_agent)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print("The client has closed the connection unexpectedly")
    return 'No'
```

Comment: I am still getting the error. Can you edit on the repl, please?

Comment: can you once check in the above repl, please? It is not working on my side